# Reducing memory usage when comparing two iterables

Tags: python

I'm changing code that writes data to a DB, so I have a dump (a text file) of an earlier run to compare against, to ensure that my changes don't screw things up. Here goes:

```
def dbcheck(cursor):
    dbresult = list()
    cursor.execute("SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE")
    for item in cursor.fetchall():
        line = item[0] + "\n"
        dbresult.append(line)
    with open(dbdump) as f:
        for n, line in enumerate(f):
            if line != dbresult[n]:
                print("DB content does not match original data!")
```

This code runs fine, but I'm worried that `dbresult` can grow really large, so am looking for a less risky way of doing this. I'm also curious of what else can be improved.

[**sidenote**] I left out exception handling for the sake of simplicity/clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def dbcheck(cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE")
    with open(dbdump) as f:
        for item in cursor:
            if f.readline() != item + '\n'
                print("DB content does not match original data!")
```

No need to read either the whole column nor the whole file before iterating.

Answer (score 4):

Use zip to iterate over both iterators at the same time. It'll only use the memory needed to hold a single entry from each at a time.

```
def dbcheck(cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE")
    with open(dbdump) as f:
        for item, line in zip(cursor, f):
            if line != item[0] + '\n':
                print("DB content does not match original data!")
```

If using python 2.x use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`. zip puts everything in a huge list which won't be very efficient.

Comment: Looks more elegant, however wasn't there talk about stuff like zip and lambda not being very Pythonic?

Comment: Aren't you missing `cursor.fetchall()`?

Comment: @Tshepange, fetchall() returns the entire result of the query as a list. But you can also iterate over the cursor directly to get the results. Since you want to iterate over all the rows in the table, this is what you want.

Comment: I've never heard zip accused of not being pythonic, lambda and reduce, yes. But zip belongs with enumerate, itertools and all that perfectly pythonic stuff.

Comment: And to be clear, it is not as though certain features of python are unpythonic and should be avoided. The goal of pythonicity is readable code. Some features tend to produce unreadable code and thus get a bad rap.

Comment: "It'll only use the memory needed to hold a single entry from each at a time." - Under Python 3, yes, under Python 2 it will return one megalist.

Comment: @Lennart, yes I'll add that to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools.izip to avoid reading all of both sets of data before iterating. Also,  this version breaks immediately on finding a problem:

```
import itertools as it
def dbcheck(cursor):
    with open(dbdump) as f:
        cursor.execute("SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE")
        for fline, dbrec in it.izip(f, cursor):
            if fline.strip() != dbrec[0]:
                print("DB content does not match original data!")
                break
```

Here is a version that reports the line number of the file, along with the mismatched data, and continues for all lines in the file. Also note that it's not calling print as a function, but rather using parenthesis to group the expression creating the string to print (in Python 3.x it is calling print as a function):

```
import itertools as it
def dbcheck(cursor):
    with open(dbdump) as f:
        cursor.execute("SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE")
        for lineno, fline, dbrec in it.izip(it.count(), f, cursor):
            if fline.strip() != dbrec[0]:
                print("Line %d: File: %s, DB: %s" % 
                      (lineno, 
                       fline.strip(), 
                       dbrec[0].strip()))
```

Also, in Python 3, the "zip" function is the same as itertools.zip, I think.

Comment: 2 issues: the very last line, why strip `brec`, and why call it `brec` :)

Comment: Why introduce a variable, `res`? Can't we just play with `cursor`?

Comment: @Tshepang, thanks for the catch. brec in the second example should have been dbrec. I've edited the example to use the correct name.

Comment: @Tshepang, I'm stripping both the line entry and the database value assuming: 1. whitespace on the ends isn't important, and 2. there will be additional whitespace on both the file line and the database record. The file line will have the end-of-line characters, and the database record may have padding, since some drivers pad the values to the full column width.

Comment: @Tshepang, I use "res" as the resultset from the cursor only because it's more difficult to format the "for" construct with the execute() inline. It could be done, of course, but at some point naming a subexpression is as clear as anonymous composition.

Comment: @TheUNIXMan: I don't understand what you say, but can't you do `it.izip(it.count(), f, cursor)` instead of introducing res?

Comment: It depends on what "cursor" is, I guess. If it's a result from a query, you can do that. If it's a database connection, you'll have to execute the query on it, giving you a result that you can then iterate over.

Comment: Which DB driver allows you to run execute using a Connection object?

Comment: Well, now that's an interesting question... Apparently I'm not sure. I suppose you do need a cursor if I'm reading the DB API (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) right. I've been using SQL Alchemy (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) more lately which has different semantics. So iterating over a cursor is perfectly fine with the DB API. I'll update the example there.